# How to execute lengthy command in power shell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

The below array containing a lengthy a command line and I have to execute the same
This is the command for verifying `SCCM` `.MIG` file using `USMTUTIL.EXE`

```
$array = "C:\MININT\amd64\usmtutils /verify:All \\SMB001.India.kerala.net\SMPSTORED_91DAA93F$\2AE09BF0AADC04FC89E0CE8A49E8C904E44C0314A123824A7EB289CAFC258026\USMT\USMT.mig /Decrypt /key:PZSTqMLlsJAYna/ndimPT1SrSAz4JjSNH1P7Sv/8mDj8qmytPcLPE3lYzxHnMiVj/6UkdDcWmiaKqgxHO3yjZj2gu8r/j23oefWOsdyWbo4r3UX2gPvMO38np7OOabZ8B0B6A5mAYynAjfy/1e00uhIm1h6soFUWIuu3wkNevBHxkWQs4xslGlooVOn0f+1kGqe05iRWUaVZC4/yYKv3LdbFLhzRXOxVYjriao4oKCEpNEdjnDK6DRoRRrbDy8Ac > C:\temp\DENDMNPWTST008.log"
```

I tried Invoke-expression `$array`

While executing this command, Its separating into different lines and only first line is executing and showing error. But I can copy-paste and run it

```
Error: CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Comment: what error is it throwing? Use `Edit` button to add code

Comment: Below is the Error:
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoke-Expression is expecting a string argument and not a string array.

try this:

```
Invoke-Expression ($array | out-string)
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much..
 It worked and targetted log got created..... But I am getting the same error again..